# Show which rows have changed status between two tables

Tags: powerbi, compare

Relatively new to PowerBI so apologies if this is a dumb question/unachievable but I am racking my brains trying to solve this.

I have connected to two data sources (‘Current’ and ‘Previous’) which each contain an extract of Projects from out CRM system, along with a Project Status. Like so :

```
Project ID    Status
1.            Accepted
2.            Closed
3.            Closed
4.            Accepted
```

I have created a table that shows the counts of each status for each source, like so, by joining the two sources on Project ID :

```
Status     Current Count   Previous Count
Accepted   24              30
Closed     80              74
```

However, I REALLY want to show in another table what has changed between the two. Something that looks like this :

```
Project ID   Previous Status   Current Status
1            Closed             Accepted
2            Accepted           Closed
```

I think this could be achievable using some kind of merge/join of the two data sources but I am really not sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First merge two tables using merge queries on project ID column
[image]

Then using calculatedTAble apply fiter to get the required result
[image]